# How can I choose the address bitcoins are sent from?

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core, sending, coin-control

So let's say I have multiple bitcoin addresses (some of them already received bitcoins), created a new bitcoin address, received bitcoins on it and would like to use the very same address to send them elsewhere - how can I do that?

I'm using Bitcoin Core (bitcoin-qt) as of right now.

Comment: Are you trying to send bitcoins from a different address than the one to which someone sent them to you?  If so, the only way would be to send them to another address you own, and then send them to someone else from there.

Comment: @Jestin I simply want to have control over which address is used for sending bitcoins elsewhere. I guess it's not possible to locally transfer bitcoins to a new address without making that transfer public. I edited the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As long as you're running a relatively recent version of Bitcoin Core you can use Coin Control. This feature let's you pick which unspent outputs will be used in the transaction.

To enable Coin Control, go to Settings->Options->Wallet->'Enable coin control features'.

Now in the Send window, you can click 'Inputs...' to select which unspent outputs you want to use. Easy!

Answer (score 4):

Many wallets have the "Coin Control" panel where you can specifically choose which outputs to use in the transaction. Which wallet are you using?

Comment: Thanks so far! Currently I'm using the "Bitcoin Core" client as stated above. It's also called Bitcoin-qt. I'm thinking about switching to MultiBit though.